# I want to read typical data from html with python parsing

Tags: python, html, regex, api, parsing

I try to use api to read company financial data.

So I access html data and I want to parse the html data with python but i don't have any idea how can I read the typical data. There is code which can give me the html data

```
url = "http://dart.fss.or.kr/api/search.json?auth="+API_KEY \
  +"&crp_cd="+company_code + "&page_set=100" \
  +"&start_dt=19990101&bsn_tp=A001&bsn_tp=A002&bsn_tp=A003"

json_data = requests.get(url).json()
list = json_data['list']

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list)

url2 = "http://dart.fss.or.kr/dsaf001/main.do?rcpNo="+data['rcp_no'][0]


print("Total number of report : ", json_data['total_count'])

temp = requests.get(url2)

html = temp.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

Below text is part of soup which is the information of html what I get from api.

```
treeNode2 = new Tree.TreeNode({
        text: "3. asset",
        id: "6",
        cls: "text",
        listeners: {
            click: function() {viewDoc('20180515000480', '6177478', '6', '58846', '899', 'dart3.xsd');}
        }
    });
    cnt++;
```

and I want to read

```
6177478
```

from

```
{viewDoc('20180515000480', '6177478', '6', '58846', '899', 'dart3.xsd');}
```

I think that regular expression will be helpful to detect the data. However, I have not used regular expression at all so please help me.

** This code is what I tried to read data, but it didn't work at all.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\.viewDoc\("\d", "\d", "\s", "\s", "\w", "\w")', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

script = soup.find_all(pattern)
```

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I see that your regular expression is using different quotation marks then the input. Here

```
{viewDoc('20180515000480', '6177478', '6', '58846', '899', 'dart3.xsd');}
```

are `'` and in your regex are `"` - this will not match then.

Second of all - the `\d` [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) used like in your example will only match one character. If you know the number of characters you want to match then you can specify the repetition like this :

- `\d{1,4}` 1 to 4 characters - `012`, `9` will match, but `1123445682` will not because it is too long
- `\d{1,}` one or more characters - better written `\d+`
- `\d{0,}` zero or more characters - better written `\d*`

You can read more about [repetition in Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/regex.html#repeating-things) (I really think they are awesome!).

Also, there is a need for [capturing group](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/regex.html#grouping) to be specified here, so when you have your long regular expression only the stuff that is in the group will get returned. 
Here is simple example how this works

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'\b(\d+)\b')
>>> p.findall('my lucky number is 13 not 7')
['13', '7']
```

And if you want to only match the second number (like in your case) you may use the knowledge of the context when writing the regexp:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'\d+ not (\d+)')
>>> p.findall('my lucky number is 13 not 7')
['7']
```

To sum up you should use capturing groups as well as make sure that you use the right repetition specifier, here is example regexp that should work for you:

```
>>> string = "{viewDoc('20180515000480', '6177478', '6', '58846', '899', 'dart3.xsd');}"
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'viewDoc\(\'\d+\', \'(\d+)\', .+\)', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
>>> pattern.findall(string)
['6177478']
```

EDIT:
Also, when it comes to the BeautifulSoup I'd suggest using their method `find_all()` like [they show in the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument):

```
soup.find_all(string=pattern)
```

To quote the documentation to clarify what this does (emphasis mine):

> With `string` you can search for strings instead of tags. (...) you can pass in a string, **a regular expression**, a list, a function, or the value True.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried to your code with <pattern.findall(html)> then I can get what I want.
However, if I run the code with soup.find_all(string = pattern) I cannot get the information and I got a lot of string from original html text. Also I can't understance ".+\" mark.

What was the problem with Beautifulsoup module?

Comment: and I found out today that I need all of that inner information what you wrote as string, '6177478', '6', '58846', '899', 'dart3.xsd'.
But there are a lot of similar format data in html because different number means different additional file. So how can I distinguish the typical line from whole html.

Comment: Could you provide some more info (like sample output) ? I suspect that the problem might be in the (greediness of the regular expression)[https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html]. Basically it is about the difference between matching the longest and the shortest possible string that fits the pattern. The `.+` means "any character 1 or more times" - so this is where the problem might be. This can be changed to look more like your original regular expression (which probably will be the best solution here).

Comment: it's too long to write on comment area.. :( Sorry but I write another question with additional example.
here is the link [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493468/read-html-with-beautifulsoup-and-find-typical-data ]

and the some keyword printed by the code is not English.. So it will be some difficult to read I think..

Comment: the tree node what i wrote is repeat with other values. So i want to find typical value from python

Comment: Could you edit the original question to add the output of what is captured by the regular expression? In this case it would be easier for me to refine my answer to your question.